# Jquery altering background-url in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I ran into a problem using jquery in IE for a background-url. I have some html (that contains a style with a background-url) that I make a jquery object from. After that I change some properties in this object and want back the outerhtml. This all works fine in chrome, but in IE it changes the background url a bit (removing slashes and adding quotes) because of this the url is not working anymore. I can add more slashes for IE, but I was wondering why this happens and if there is a better solution?

So the following peace of code will give the same html back in chrome as was put in, but in IE it has been altered:

```
function test() {
  var logo  =  '<div class=\"item__img\" style=\"background-image: url(graphic?path=avatars\\OSDAFIJ-Employee_Large.JPEG?ts=1433171332313)\"></div>';
  var $logo = $(logo);
  var logoOuterHtml = $logo.prop('outerHTML');
  console.info(logo + " || " + logoOuterHtml);
  alert(logo === logoOuterHtml);
}

test();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7fs4xvr/